# Raspberry Pi Dashboard with websnippets

Tags: dashboard

If you are already familiar with the apple dashbaord: there is an option where you can include a web snippet. 
This snippet is a small part of a website.
If I take for instance facebook: only the 3 icons at the top can be selected. And that is updated all the time.

**What I want to achieve:**
I would like to have a screen, where I have a dashboard with web snippets open all the time. But I want to do this with a Raspberry PI (2).

I am looking for any ways to achieve this. But I am not familiar with any programs that can do this. Or if there is a way to do this with HTML I am also interested to hear it.